# android database rekey throws exception

Tags: android, database, sqlite

```
    i have two database in my project 

    Database1 db1;
    db1.open();
    String newKey= "newKey";
    db1.rekey(currentKEy, newKey);
    db1.close();


    DataBase2 db2;
    db2.rekey(currentKEy, newKEy);
```

## LOGCAT

```
Failed to setLocale() when constructing, closing the database
 net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: file is encrypted or is not a database
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.native_setLocale(Native Method)
 net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.setLocale(SQLiteDatabase.java:2102)
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1968)
 net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:901)
 net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:944)
 net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:107)
 com.acs.android.fwk.database.SQLiteOpenHelper.open(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:98)
```

it is this for DB1 it is working fine, but for DB2 it throws Exception 
is it compulsory to open database before doing rekey....

Comment: Maybe you should open() firstly?

Comment: @OrestSavchak -- you mean to say i have to open DB2 also with existing key ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SQLiteException: file is encrypted or is not a database
```

I faced this issue. My scenario is i enter the database password wrong.

I guess you are accessing your Db2 with your Db1 password. 
This is one scenario maybe there is other reasons you get the error.